# Extraction and printing of key-value pair from a text file using Perl

Tags: perl, search, hash, extract

I have a text file temp.txt which contains entries like,

```
cinterim=3534
cstart=517
cstop=622
ointerim=47
ostart=19
ostop=20
```

Note: key-value pairs may be arranged in new line or all at once in one line separated by space.

I am trying to print and store these values in DB for corresponding keys using Perl.  But I am getting many errors and warnings.  Right now I am just trying to print those values.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE,"/root/temp.txt") or die "Unable to open file:$!\n";

while (my $line = <FILE>) {
  # optional whitespace, KEY, optional whitespace, required ':', 
  # optional whitespace, VALUE, required whitespace, required '.'
  $line =~ m/^\s*(\S+)\s*:\s*(.*)\s+\./;
  my @pairs = split(/\s+/,$line);
  my %hash = map { split(/=/, $_, 2) } @pairs;

  printf "%s,%s,%s\n", $hash{cinterim}, $hash{cstart}, $hash{cstop};

}
close(FILE);
```

Could somebody provide help to refine my program.

Comment: What errors and what warnings are you getting. Please show them here.

Comment: Your script doesn't fit your data set -- the script is splitting the data line on ':' ending with '.', but your data pairs are separated by '=', not ending in '.'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', '/root/temp.txt' or die "Unable to open file:$!\n";
my %hash = map { split /=|\s+/; } <$fh>;
close $fh;
print "$_ => $hash{$_}\n" for keys %hash;
```

What this code does:

`<$fh>` reads a line from our file, or in list context, all lines and returns them as an array.

Inside `map` we split our line into an array using the regexp `/= | \s+/x`. This means: split when you see a `=` or a sequence of whitespace characters. This is just a condensed and beautified form of your original code.

Then, we cast the list resulting from `map` to the `hash` type. We can do that because the item count of the list is even. (Input like `key key=value` or `key=value=value`will throw an error at this point).

After that, we print the hash out. In Perl, we can interpolate hash values inside strings directly and don't have to use `printf` and friends except for special formatting.

The `for` loop iterates over all keys (returned in the `$_` special variable), and `$hash{$_}` is the corresponding value. This could also have been written as

```
while (my ($key, $val) = each %hash) {
  print "$key => $val\n";
}
```

where `each` iterates over all key-value pairs.

Comment: Could you add an explanation, please?

Comment: @cdtits:Thanks a lot, it helped.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
use warnings;

my %data = ();

open FILE, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
while(<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    $data{$1} = $2 while /\s*(\S+)=(\S+)/g;
}
close FILE;

print $_, '-', $data{$_}, $/ for keys %data;
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to slurp the entire file into memory and assign key/value pairs to the hash using a regular expression.

This program shows the technique

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = do {
  open my $fh, '<', '/root/temp.txt' or die $!;
  local $/;
  <$fh> =~ /(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)/g;
};

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;
```

**output**

```
{
  cinterim => 3534,
  cstart   => 517,
  cstop    => 622,
  ointerim => 47,
  ostart   => 19,
  ostop    => 20,
}
```