# Perl Program Issue, how to print scalar and array values together of hash

Tags: perl, hash

I also faced the same issue and I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844679/extraction-and-printing-of-key-value-pair-from-a-text-file-using-perl/11844903?newreg=e80a512a0c1e4ae4a05c227815827c5d). It helped a lot, but it is useful when all values are scalar but my program contains both array and scalar values. so I am able to print scalar values but unable to print array values. Please suggest what we need to add?

Code:

```
#!/grid/common/bin/perl 

use warnings; 

require ("file.pl"); 

while (my ($key, $val) = each %hash) 
{ 
     print "$key => $val\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Share your code/workaround first.

Comment: #!/grid/common/bin/perl
use warnings;
require ("file.pl");
while (my ($key, $val) = each %hash) {
  print "$key => $val\n";
}

Comment: #Pirate X please check the code

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma . What  is the file.pl contain . How could come scalar and array tell me briefly

Comment: Is your goal to print the values for debugging? Is there a specific format you want the output to be in?

Answer (score 5):

Non-scalar values require dereferencing, otherwise you will just print out `ARRAY(0xdeadbeef)` or `HASH(0xdeadbeef)` with the memory addresses of those data structures.

Have a good read of Perl Data Structure Cookbook: [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
as well as Perl References: [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Since you did not provide your data, here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash = ( foo => 'bar',
             baz => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
             qux => { a => 123, b => 234 }
);

while (my ($key, $val) = each %hash) {
    my $ref_type = ref $val;
    if ( not $ref_type ) {
        # SCALAR VARIABLE
        print "$key => $val\n";
        next;
    }

    if ('ARRAY' eq $ref_type) {
        print "$key => [ " . join(',', @$val) . " ]\n";
    } elsif ('HASH' eq $ref_type) {
        print "$key => {\n";
        while (my ($k, $v) = each %$val) {
            print "    $k => $v\n";
        }
        print "}\n";
    } else {
        # Otherstuff...
        die "Don't know how to handle data of type '$ref_type'";
    }
 }
```

**Output**

```
baz => [ 1,2,3 ]
qux => {
    a => 123
    b => 234
}
foo => bar
```

For more complicated structures, you will need to recurse.

`Data::Printer` is useful for dumping out complicated structures.

Comment: you are welcome.  keep asking questions, we are here to help.