# How to save systemctl show output (k=v) to perl hash?

Tags: perl

The output of `systemctl` command is in the form:

```
k1=v1
k2=v2
...
```

How to save it into a Perl hash? Do I need to substitute = to => first?

Comment: A question about a very similar topic that should give you the right idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844679/extraction-and-printing-of-key-value-pair-from-a-text-file-using-perl

Comment: How do you get this output, you call systemctl with `qx`?

Comment: `my %hash = map { split '=' } qx($cmd);`, where `$cmd` is your `systemctl` command which returns lines of form `a=b`.  Read the linked page, and find more. Add checks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to substitute = to => first?

No, you don't want to generate Perl code.

```perl
my %hash;
for split(/\n/, $output) {
   my ($k, $v) = split(/=/, $_, 2);
   $hash{$k} = $v;
}
```

or

```perl
my %hash =
   map { split(/=/, $_, 2) }
      split(/\n/, $output);
```